# React, Router only `/` works, getting "Cannot GET .." for other routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I know there are multiple similar questions out there but there is no appropriate solution to any of those (none worked for me).

I am just stuck at this point and couldnt find any solution, need help!

Notes

1. Not using any server (like Node.js or anything),
2. React (version - 16.4.1)
3. react-router-dom (version - 4.3.1)

### Context

***`index.js`*** file (the app entry point)

```
// index.js
//----------------------------------------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import Store from './store';
import Home from '../components/home';

const App = () => (
    <Provider store={Store}>
        <Router>
            <Home/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

***`home.js`*** the only component mentioned in `index.js` (above file)

```
// home.js
//----------------------------
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Signup from './signup';
import Login from './login';

class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Signup}/>       // Case (1) 
                <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup}/> // Case (2)
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>   // Case (3)
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, null)(Home)
```

---

***`signup.js`*** A simple view with **`<Link>`** implementation

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Signup extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 <Link to='/signup'>Link to Signup</Link>  // For Route Case (2) in signup.js 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default connect(null, null)(Signup)
```

---

### The PROBLEM

So when the app is started:

1. The application runs, renders - the **`signup.js`** with a link - **"Link to Signup"** (url: `localhost:8080`)
2. I trigger `"/"` through Browser (url: `localhost:8080`) - **IT WORKS!**
3. I click *"Link to Signup"* (url: `localhost:8080/signup`) - **IT WORKS!**
4. Now I reload (url: `localhost:8080/signup`) - **ERROR!** `"Cannot GET /signup"`
5. If I trigger `"/signup"` through Browser - **ERROR!** `"Cannot GET /signup"`
6. If I trigger `"/login"` through Browser - **is ALWAYS ERROR** `"Cannot GET /login"`

Comment: This is a common problem in Single Page Applications. When you try to hit `localhost:8080/signup` via your browser URL, your browser makes a request asking for `/signup` which would result in a 404 as your server will not have that file/folder. It works when you click on a link internally because React will be already loaded and it probably handles the transition to the correct route for you. Usually, a simple fix for this would be to configure your server to send all requests to your `index.html` file. How you would configure this depends on what you are using to create your HTTP server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node (Express) / React app only works locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970667/node-express-react-app-only-works-locally)

Comment: It seems to work here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6xv10l73kk